# batch rename files using a user specified variable

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I am wondering if it is possible to rename folders, the contained sub-folders, and contained files using a prompted user specified variable?

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further details...

Comment: @bryeguy Please provide some more information to help users answer your question....such as;

Sample folder/file structure....ie. Does the primary folder also have files in it? or only the sub-folder?

What sort of naming convention do you want the folders and files to have?  ...just a numbered sequence? or is it based on date and times, or perhaps file names?